# Prevent member objects referencing the same list

Tags: python, list, object

This should be simple...

```
class Object:
    x = 0
    y = []

a = Object()
b = Object()

a.x = 1
b.x = 2
print a.x, b.x
# output: 1 2
# works as expected

a.y.append(3)
b.y.append(4)
print a.y, b.y
# output: [3, 4] [3, 4]
# same list is referenced  how to fix?
# desired output: [3] [4]
```

As far as I can tell, `a.y` and `b.y` reference the same list.  How can I get them to be separate?  Preferably, without adding an `__init__` method.

Comment: print a.x,b,y should print this :  1 []

Comment: This is what `__init__` is for. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @gnibbler if I knew exactly how Python objects worked I wouldn't be here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is that you actually have actually redefined x as an **instance** level attribute, and your class definition had them as both **class** level attributes.

If you do this, you can see your original x is still at 0.

```
>>> Object.x
0
```

As you don't create a new list, it's taking the class attribute. If you were to do this:

```
>>> a.y = []
>>> b.y = []
>>> a.y.append(1)
>>> b.y.append(2)
>>> print a.y, b.y
[1] [2]
```

That is what you are expecting. Really though you should be defining your class like this:

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = []
        self.x = 0
```

(and don't use Object as a classname!)

Comment: Beautiful explanation, thank you!  And don't worry, my real objects are not `Object`s :)

Answer (score 3):

You're creating the value of `y` only once, when you define the class. To assign a different list to each instance of `y`, you do need an init function. Just put `self.y = []` in `__init__` and it will work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to setup **instance** properties instead of **class** properties is to use `__init__`

When you reference an **instance** property (like `a.y`) the parser tries to return that first but if it isn't found the **class** property (`Object.y`) is returned.

In your case only defined a **class** property which is shared by all instances.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that is creating the `__init__` method

```
class Object:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 0
    self.y = []
```

That way upon Object's construction, a new value will be assined to `x` and a new List will be **created** for `y`.

The way you were doing before creates two class/static variables to Object, but only `y` stays the same because it holds statically only a reference to the true List, reflecting to all instances of Object.

More on class/static variables on this other question:
[Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

*Sorry if I used the wrong terms, I'm more of a Java person ;-)